# postfix-gmail problems: This mail is unauthenticated, which poses a security risk to the 550-5.7.26 sender

Tags: postfix, gmail

Can someone help, who had that problem too? Postfix and Dovecot is freshed installed and configurated for SSL but if i try to send an email to my gmail account i get that error msg.

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.26 This mail is unauthenticated, which poses a
security risk to the 550-5.7.26 sender and Gmail users, and has been
blocked. The sender must 550-5.7.26 authenticate with at least one of SPF
or DKIM. For this message, 550-5.7.26 DKIM checks did not pass and SPF
check for [...] did not pass with ip:
[...]. The sender should visit 550-5.7.26
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for 550 5.7.26
instructions on setting up authentication.
b11-20020adff24b000000b003063d97a9bbsi10649016wrp.1043 - gsmtp
```

I know, I know. Read the manual https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication what I do, but its a bit hardcore because i dont understand all differences between spf, dkim and so on. Is that new from gmail, because one year ago it worked without that stuff. Maybe it was the TLS settings or whatever, because now i want to use only port 993 and 465 without the rest. Can someone give me some hints and help to find a readable solution for that? thx

### update 1

I can send emails to other servers over only port 465 but cant recive an reply email from them to 993

```
2023-05-12T17:17:16.122149+02:00 web-p3 dovecot: imap(mail@a1.x.y)<18446><QSlzc4D71vIFtAyA>: Disconnected: Logged out in=392 out=3065 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
```

Comment: Gmail used to not strictly enforce this rule and afaict they still only do when your published domain or hostname looks funny. But if you did see that message, that means you have to setup some form of authentication to push messages towards google. Which you should be doing anyway, if you are running a mail server, so not much changed.

Comment: @anx hi. i tried to send to gmail and thats the response. what you mean with funny hostnames? do you mean if my local server hostname is a1 and my domain ISP hostname is b2? so not equal over the same x.y domain? and what do you mean with setup authentification to push messages. thought if i set the ssl right, that would happens automaticly. sorry for that questions, but i am a noob at mailservers. and btw. from that article: "Important: Starting November 2022, new senders who send email to personal Gmail accounts must set up either SPF or DKIM. ". sry i saw that just right now =(

Comment: @anx thats so strange. i can send to other mailservers and it works (here it is the mailserver of my university). i recived an test email from mail@a1.x.y) so it seams that the port 465 works as he has to but i get that message if i try to send an reply to the mail@a1.x.y: **see update 1** i dont get any mail to my box =( seams dovecot 933 problems

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to pretty much exactly what Google has recommended you do. Yes, that absolutely would involve understanding a number of supplementary (to SMTP itself) technologies.

It is hardcore, at least in the sense that in today's world you are not left with  much choice other than setting up and complying with (at the very least) the demands of popular operators, or paying someone else to do so for you.

I would strongly discourage running your own mail server on the internet before investing substantial time into reading up on how the various protocols, mechanisms and ports work together. How you interact with your server via port 465 and 993 is generally quite separated from how mail exchanges interact with each other on port 25 and with each others names via DNS.

Comment: The description on Google would be great if they'd provide more information.  E.g., I'm not sure who my email provider is to register the email address with and they don't tell me how to find out.  I've been using the same email address since the 90's and never had to do anything with time since I started.  The automatically deduct the payments from my account, but there's no contact info  Is it saying that I have to separately register every email address I send email to?  if I move my email to google, can I keep the same email address?  Or do I need a gmail.com domain in my email addess?